# Open exe from Windows Registry doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-registry

I need to start my application on Windows startup.

I used this command to set the registry:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "ProgramName" /d "ProgramPath" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ
```

I checked, and the registry is ok. I tried to put on HKEY_CURRENT_USER too.

But both isn't working. My application need root privileges to work.

Did I forgot something to get it working?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to schedule a task?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I was having problems whit it. Sometimes it didn't work. And any user can download this software, so it is interesting to do it programmatically directly on software.

Comment: Software that runs when Windows starts and has high privileges in Windows usually is a service. Microsoft documentation describes how to make a service. Alternatively, there is the "srvany" program that allows easily run certain programs as a service.

Comment: I think your biggest problem is you are using a reg_expand_sz when everything else there uses REG_SZ